# How to PRINT web page in larger font type?

Tags: safari, printing, font, text

I need to print a web page for a person with bad eyesight. I don't want to change my Safari font settings, as *I* can see web pages just fine. I only want to *print* the web page in a larger size.

I have upscaled the font size in the print settings to a larger percentage, say 150% for example - however, the result cuts off the edges into different printed pages, rather than actually scaling the text and fitting it to the pages properly.

For example, this web text appears in the normally scaled print size as:
[image]

However, when scaled to 150%, page 1 of the print preview shows:

[image]

And, page 2 of the print preview shows:

[image]

You can see how the text is cut off on the right side and moved to the next page.

What I want is the text to be enlarged and scaled so that even if only a few words fit on a line, say, the print will still flow downwards appropriately:

> "Cabbage leaves are stuffed with ground beef,
>   rice, then simmered in tomato soup. Works
>   great in the oven or a slow cooker. Serve with
>   ...
>
> -the image might flow down to here-

and so on...

Comment: And, if anyone is curious, the web page I'm currently trying to print is [Golabki (Stuffed Cabbage Rolls) - Printer Friendly - Allrecipes.com](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/234975/golabki-stuffed-cabbage-rolls/print/?recipeType=Recipe&servings=8&isMetric=false)

Comment: Turn the paper landscape for a quick fix, but I usually drag recipes out in sections & rebuild in Pages, to give them a coherent look in my binder.

Comment: Tried that, @Tetsujin. The text is no larger; it's just spread more across the page.

Comment: I'd go for Pages then. Finer control & you can save a template to use next time.

Comment: Perhaps a custom CSS stylesheet file for formatting print layouts would work but that is quite advanced for the average user.

Comment: @bjbk, would you know of short, simple examples ?  There are 700 questions https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+%5Bprinting%5D+stylesheet ...

Comment: @denis, using custom CSS is a complex topic, but I'll give you an example that worked for me on this Golabki page: I used the developer tools to find the recipe box. It was assigned a CSS class called `recipe-print__container`. I then created a text file that I called golabki.css. Inside the file I put: `.recipe-print__container { font-size: 2em !important; }`. Then, with the recipe page showing in Safari, I pressed CMD+, to show Safari's preferences. Under Advanced->Style Sheet, I selected the file. The recipe box content then had larger text, and I could easily print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest & fastest way to do it is to temporarily change preferences for minimal font-size.

1. open in Safari's Application Menu: `Safari / Preferences` or use hotkey `⌘`+`,`
2. there tab `Advanced`
3. there turn on checkbox "Never use font size smaller then XX" where XX is your preferred font-size. That is it.
4. print it

[image: Safari's preferences : advanced (part)]

---

So the next screenshot demonstrates the result. On the left side not changed min-font-size (opened in Preview.app as prepare/preview before printing). On the right side - all is same but min-font-size is 24.

[image]